# How to get Used disk space in Windows Phone c#

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

Is there any way to find out how much disk space has been occupied by isolated storage, one way in my mind is to iterated through all the files and get their size if there is any other way please share.

**Update:**
 I should be more clear about my requirement.

Actually I want to display app disk space usage within application, I already know about `IsolatedStorageFile.AvailableFreeSpace` but it does not resolve my problem. On the other hand [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorage.usedsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) claims that there is an `IsolatedStorage` class available in Windows Phone 8.0 Sdk under `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` which provides `UsedSize` property to evaluate used disk size but infact this class is not available in sdk. So if anybody has an idea about it please share.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IsolatedStorage.UsedSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorage.usedsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get the used space. And use the [IsolatedStorage.AvailableFreeSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorage.availablefreespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to [anticipate Out-of-Space conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fzedtyx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This will obviously not give you the entire used disk space of the phone, but only the usage of your own applications Isolated Storage.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I asked

Comment: @MubasharAhmad: The APIs for what you want don't exist (outside of MS and manufacturers).  This is as good as it gets right now.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT: IsolatedStorage.UsedSize msdn claims that IsolatedStorageFile is derived from IsolatedStorage class but in real its not, So apparently i can't access the UsedSize property in WindowsPhone 8.0 sdk. I have already contact microsoft over this let you know when they respond back.

Comment: @Will: I have a different problem to resolve, i want to inform user that how much storage my application is occupying, this has nothing to do with AvailableFreeSpace.